# How can we upload workflows from Eclipse to Sandbox?

Tags: workflow, force.com, eclipse

We refreshed our sandbox from PROD and now we have some before refreshing .workflow files that we need to upload to our refreshed sandbox.

Is this possible?

Please, let me know how proceed as I am strugling to do so. I am using force.com Eclipse. I tried moving the needed *.workflow files to the src\workflow folder and upload them to the sandbox but it is not happening.

Thanks

Comment: why not use change sets from PROD to sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the .workflow file to the workflow**S** folder (note the S) and save to server. It may be good to add the workflows to your package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Workflow</name>
</types>
```